# Slot not called for signal finished of QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qt-signals, qnetworkreply

I want to send a post request to a server and I do something like this:

```
function makePost(){
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    qDebug()<<"1";
    bool ret = connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    qDebug()<<"2: " <<ret;

    QUrl serviceUrl = QUrl("http://someurl/json");
    QNetworkRequest request(serviceUrl);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");

    QString content = "";
    networkManager->post(request, content.toUtf8());
}
```

But the slot `serviceRequestFinished()` is not called at all! I must mention that I used Wireshark to track the request/response and I found that the request(post) is being sent and the server returns a response back with status `200`(ok). Also the `ret` variable returns `true`, i.e. the connection between signal and slot was made successfully. Any of you have any idea why this doesn't work? Thank you!:)

**EDIT**

The code that cause the problem - see my answer - is this:

```
{    
     MyObjectWithSlot obj;
     obj.makePost();
}
```

Comment: Is that all your code? You  dont have a CONNECT(...) to connect the signal to a slot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I found my mistake! You can downvote as much as you want my answer or question but I would like to answer if someone else has a similar problem!

Be careful! The object that has the slot should be in scope and not terminate(destroyed) before the slot is called. As you can see in the edited part of my question, the object is created, it calls a function and then it's out of scope!

```
{
    MyObjectWithSlot obj;
    return obj.makePost();
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked out. I was about to ask where you defined your serviceRequestFinished(...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Qt to connect the signal `finished()`, which is called when `post()` finishes, to a slot of your choice. Something like the following:

```
QObject::connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
                 this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

For more information about signals and slots, see [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).